Animating a SVG/Image moving on a certain path (vertically and horizontally) along the screen while the user scrolls
The animation (one and more svg's) should move to different coordinates while the user scrolls down the site. Im struggeling with the horizontal movement which should be controlled by vertical scrolling - means if the user scrolls down the site should be fixed in the viewport until the svg moved from pos x1 to pos x2 in the same speed it would move vertically.
The idea is animating the svg's in a canvas element that spans the whole webpage.
Its for the landing page of a science competition where only opensource content is allowed so Greensock/gsap wont work.
Thanks a lot for your support!
    move_horizontal(y_value, x1, x2){
        let diff_x = (marker_x())
        let stepsize = diff_x / 10 // positive and negative values
        console.log(stepsize)
        console.log("thisx: " + this.x)
        if (this.y === y_value && this.x > x1 + 1 && this.x < x2 - 1){
            document.getElementsByClassName('scrollbox')[0].classList.add('fixed');        
            if (this.x + stepsize > x2){
                this.x = x2
                document.getElementsByClassName('scrollbox')[0].classList.add('unset');
            }
            else if (this.x + stepsize < x1){
                this.x = x1
                document.getElementsByClassName('scrollbox')[0].classList.add('unset');
            }
            else {
                this.x += stepsize
            }
        }
    }

    function animate(anchor_coordinates, object) {
        let marker = viewport_marker();    
        requestAnimationFrame(() => {
            object.move_vertical(anchor_coordinates[0].y, anchor_coordinates[1].y, marker);
            object.move_horizontal(anchor_coordinates[1].y, anchor_coordinates[0].x,      anchor_coordinates[2].x)
            // Clear the canvas
            ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
            // Draw the image
            ctx.drawImage(object.image, object.x, object.y, object.width, object.height);
            animate(anchor_coordinates, object);
        });
}

I tried creating a scrollbox div that encapsulates all other elements and set its css position properties to fixed when a point on the webpage is reached where the svg should move horizontal. The body element was outside the scrollbox and had a large heigth so that i could scroll while everything else was fixed hoping that i could then use the changing y values to move my svg to the desired x coordinates while the user only needs to scroll.

Your current example doesn't clarify how you're retrieving svg "on-path" coordinates related to a svg path (e.g via getpointAtLenght()). Please add a running snippet to show what you've already achieved (and what's not working). This post "Move an element along the svg path while placing it in center viewport" may also provide some concepts to adapt.
